# Adding a route master admin feature

Tags: flutter

```
{
    if (data != null) {
        getData(ref, data);
        return loggedInRoute;
    }

    return loggedOutRoute;
}
```

I am using the logged in and logged out feature of the route master package, but according to the admin information in my userprovide, I need to redirect to the loggedinroute. I could not find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing the `loggedInRoute` to the `RouteMaster` widget as the `initialRoute` parameter.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      home: RouteMaster(
        initialRoute: loggedInRoute,
        onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
          if (UserProvider.of(context).isAdmin) {
            return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => loggedInRoute,
              settings: settings,
            );
          } else {
            return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => loggedOutRoute,
              settings: settings,
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```